# File.Exists no funciona como se espera

Tags: c#, funciones

Uso la funcion `File.Exists(path)` y la ruta que le paso, sí que existe, pero el resultado me da a *false*.

Otra de las cosas es que, cuando ejecuta el `File.Create(path)` me levanta la excepcion diciendo que no tengo permisos, pero soy administrador con permiso total.

Comment: Hola! puedes pegar parte del codigo así como la ruta que estás pasando?

Comment: Estaba pasando una ruta de un directorio en vez de un archivo, por eso no me funcionaba.

Comment: sobre que carpeta estas validando? porque no veo que sea un problema de Exists() o Create() sino de la ruta que quieres validar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para comprobar existencia de archivos: `File.Exists(path)`

Para comprobar existencia de directorios: `Directory.Exists(path)`